# Grammar [en-us] to [en-gb]

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I need help to set the grammar type in my code to en-GB as by default it is en-US. Here is the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
        _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Tahmid\Documents\Commands.txt")))));
        _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
        _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
```

I'v done some research into the topic, and because I'm using `System.Speech.Recognition` I know it has something to do with "Culture". You would likely know more than me because I am new to this.  How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [set the culture on your `GrammarBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammarbuilder.culture.aspx) to en-GB

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
    var grammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder(
              new Choices(
              File.ReadAllLines(
                @"C:\Users\Tahmid\Documents\Commands.txt")));
    grammarBuilder.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
    _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(grammarBuilder));
    _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
    _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
}
```

Comment: EDIT, Nevermind, That's on my end. Thanks for your answer! It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the culture on the current thread, like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

Comment: Probably better to set the cultureInfo on the `GrammarBuilder` than risk messing other things up in the thread.